# How do you stop an iframe from saying "Site refused to connect"?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm kind of new to iframes, since I just started. And I've just tried a simple iframe tag, just to see what would happen. Let's just say I want to link it to Stack Overflow.
The following is the snippet I took that leads to what happened.

[image: FFJFJFJFJFJFJFJF]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Network tab of your browser's devtools, you'll see more detail about what happens when you try to embed something in an iframe.

Many sites disallow themselves from being embedded by sending the [X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) to browsers.

Comment: So, this was in the console. `Refused to frame 'SITE NAME HERE' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive`. How do I solve this problem?